# Unable to write to Samba share as guest user after upgrading to Samba 4

Tags: samba, freebsd

I recently upgraded to Samba 4.4.8 from 3.x on a FreeBSD 11 system. During the upgrade, I found out that `security = share` was removed and halfway replaced with `map to guest = Bad Password`. After changing that, I was able to connect to the share as a guest, but not able to write to the share; clients say permission denied.

Looking through the logs, I found this error:

```
[2017/01/08 20:17:59.632441,  3] ../source3/smbd/error.c:82(error_packet_set)
  NT error packet at ../source3/smbd/error.c(165) cmd=162 (SMBntcreateX) NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Here's `/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf`:

```
[global]
   workgroup = MYGROUP
   server string = share

   # security and map to guest were the only settings changed after upgrading
   security = user
   map to guest = Bad Password
   guest account = share

   log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   log level = 3

   dns proxy = no

[share]
   path = /tank/share
   public = yes
   guest ok = yes
   only guest = yes
   writable = yes
   force user = share
   force group = share
   printable = no
```

And the ownership of the directories:

```
$ ls -l -d /tank /tank/share
drwxr-xr-x  10 root   wheel   12 Dec  5 04:50 /tank
drwxr-xr-x  43 share  share  101 Jan  3 05:04 /tank/share
```

In all my googling for this issue, problems seemed to be either not setting `writable = yes`, not doing `force user`, not setting a `guest account`, or the user not having write access to the target directory, but those all look fine.

This happens for both Windows and Linux clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what fixed it, but one three changes did:

- changing `map to guest` to `Bad User` (as documented in the [basic config file](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server#Creating_a_Basic_smb.conf_File) example on the Samba wiki)
- removing `guest account` from the global config
- removing `public = yes` from the share config

```
[global]
   workgroup = MYGROUP
   server string = share

   security = user
   map to guest = Bad User
   # guest account = share

   log file = /var/log/samba4/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   log level = 3

   dns proxy = no

[share]
   path = /tank/share
   # public = yes
   guest ok = yes
   only guest = yes
   writable = yes
   force user = share
   force group = share
   printable = no
```